# How can I access the automagically-created CLOUD_STORAGE_ACCOUNT connection string in Azure?

Tags: azure, azure-storage

When you associate your website with a storage account, a connection string is automatically created in your configuration:

[image]

However, I can't figure out how to get this connection string at runtime.  The old-school

> ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CLOUD_STORAGE_ACCOUNT"]

returns `null`, and I tried (out of desperation)

> CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("CLOUD_STORAGE_ACCOUNT");

which, of course, didn't work as it's not an *application setting*.  All examples I've found have people essentially reproducing the configuration string as a **new** connection string (which then can be accessed by the first method) or as an app setting (accessed by the second).

This seems stupid.  Its already created by Azure, and its guaranteed to be more correct than what I would create.

**So how can I get *aholt* of the "CLOUD_STORAGE_ACCOUNT" connection string at runtime?**

**Edit:**

I'm configuring the website via the portal.  Linked my storage account under **Linked Resources**.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Details about configuring (including connection strings) are here: https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/manage/services/web-sites/how-to-configure-websites/

It's a bit cryptic.  But, to use a connection string named "CLOUD_STORAGE_ACCOUNT" configured in Azure Portal, you must have a connection string named "CLOUD_STORAGE_ACCOUNT" in your local web.config (in the connectionStrings) section.  When publishing, the one configured in the Portal will *replace* the one in your web.config.

Then you can use `ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CLOUD_STORAGE_ACCOUNT"].ConnectionString`

Comment: Aaaah, yeah, the ones in the web do override, don't they?  That might be a decent enough solution.  I'll check it out after work.

Comment: Er, I'll check it sometime.